# Nginx throwing 404 error on php cripts and on subdomain only

Tags: php, linux, nginx, vps

I have a problem on nginx : everything worked fine until i tried to add a subdomain. Now, every time I try to get a php file from my browser, I get a 404 error. But the strangest thing is that on my main domain, it still works. There are no error logs on nginx, and on access log I can see the 404 HTTP response. Does anyone have an answer ?

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/domain.com**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com *.domain.com;

    access_log /var/www/domain.com/logs/nginx_access.log vhosts;
    error_log /var/www/domain.com/logs/nginx_error.log;

    location / {
        root /var/www/domain/www;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }
    error_page 500 501 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
        root /var/www/nginx-default;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        include snippets/fastcgi.conf;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name domain.com *.domain.com;

    access_log /var/www/domain.com/logs/nginx_access.log vhosts;
    error_log /var/www/domain.com/logs/nginx_error.log;

    root /var/www/domain.com/www;

####### SSL Directives #######
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /var/www/domain.com/config/ssl/fullchain.domain.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/domain.com/config/ssl/privkey.domain.com.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
        root /var/www/domain.com/www;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        include snippets/fastcgi.conf;
        }


    ###
    # Rewrite rules
    ###

    ### 
    # Rewrite rule 1 : redirect www.domain.com to domain.com
    ###

    if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*)domain\.com$) {
        rewrite ^(.*) //domain.com/$1 permanent;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name sub.domain.com;

    location / {
        root /var/www/domain.com/sub/www;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    ###
    # SSL   
    ###

    ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /var/www/domain.com/config/ssl/fullchain.sub.domain.com.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /var/www/domain.com/config/ssl/privkey.sub.domain.com.pem;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES25$;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
                include snippets/fastcgi.conf;
        }


    ### 
    # Logging 
    ###

    access_log /var/www/domain.com/logs/nginx_access.log vhosts;
    error_log /var/www/domain.com/logs/nginx_error.log;

}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub.domain.com;

    location / {
        root /var/www/domain.com/sub/www;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;   
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
                include snippets/fastcgi.conf;
        }


    ###
    # Logging
    ###

    access_log /var/www/domain.com/logs/nginx_access.log vhosts;
    error_log /var/www/domain.com/logs/nginx_error.log;
}
```

**The 2 last lines of the error log**

```
2017/11/26 15:44:37 [error] 25444#25444: *10 directory index of "/var/www/domain.com/sub/www/files/" is forbidden, client: 00.00.000.000, server: sub.domain.com, request: "GET /files/ HTTP/2.0", host: "sub.domain.com"
2017/11/26 15:46:10 [error] 25444#25444: *14 open() "/var/www/domain.com/sub/www/this_file_does_not_exist.p" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 00.00.000.000, server: sub.domain.com, request: "GET /this_file_does_not_exist.p HTTP/2.0", host: "sub.domain.com"
```

It seems to behave normally : it returns 403 forbidden when trying to acces to a folder without index, and 404 when trying to get a non existing file. But, here is noting about 404 on php files, even if requested.

**last lines of access.log**

```
domain.com 00.00.000.000 - - [26/Nov/2017:15:45:32 +0100] "GET /index.php HTTP/2.0" 200 176 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36"
sub.domain.com 00.00.000.000 - - [26/Nov/2017:15:45:42 +0100] "GET /index.php HTTP/2.0" 404 261 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36"
sub.domain.com 00.00.000.000 - - [26/Nov/2017:15:46:10 +0100] "GET /this_file_does_not_exist.p HTTP/2.0" 404 260 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36"
sub.domain.com 00.00.000.000 - - [26/Nov/2017:15:46:24 +0100] "GET /main_style.css HTTP/2.0" 200 2931 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36"
```

On main domain, php files have a 200 response and are displayed in browser. But, in subdomain, they return a 404 response, like they were not here. But, index.php is in the same folder than main_style.css, and main_style.css returns a 200 response and is displayed.

I really don't know what to do for this to work. If anyone could help he would be very welcome.

EDIT : Here is a the HTTP response when trying to GET https://sub.domain.com/, via hurl.it. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfYxM.png)

PS : sub.domain.com is not my domain name. I just changed it to avoid this post being above my website in Google.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `root` directive.

Where `location /` and `location ~ \.php$` share the same root, it is usual to specify the root in the `server` block and allow both locations to inherit the same value.

For example:

```
server {
    ...
    root /var/www/domain.com/www;

    location / {
        ...
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
    }
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for more.